# HTML5 Web Workers for huge md5 sum

Tags: javascript, html, hash, md5, web-worker

I'm already using the web workers scenario to get md5 sum from local files, before upload - and it's working well for small files.

But for my app purposes I need to get the hash from a file with 5gb, and all md5 implementations that I found need to allocate all content in one string - what results in an allocation size overflow.

It's possible to get the md5 js hash with memory pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a algorithm for md5 that supports streaming. There are streaming md5 algorithms that you may want to look into. For example, here is one:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-md5
- https://github.com/fastest963/stream-js-md5

Note that even though the example I give is an NPM package, it does not have any external dependencies. You should be able to use it in the browser.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! It's exactly what I need